# Function not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The below defined function will open a dialog from a loop

```
 $http.post(url,req, "")
  .then(function (response) {
     for (var r = 0; r < response.data.items.length ; r++){
         foo(response.data.items[r], r);
     }

function foo(i, j) {
    $rootScope.dialogOpen = function () {
            alert('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j );
        }
}
```

While debugging I am able to hit the function but the dialog isn't opening . What went wrong .

Comment: impossible to tell, you are defining a dialogOpen method, are you supposed to be calling it?

Comment: Are you talking about the modals?

Comment: OP question is not clear enough!

Comment: I got the solution thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like `$rootScope.dialogOpen()` gets defined but never called.  The body of your function `foo` declares `$rootScope.dialogOpen()` but this is never called.

I am not sure how your app is structured, but it's almost certain you shouldn't be defining `$rootScope.dialogOpen()` inside of `foo`.  The dialogOpen function should be declared elsewhere such as in your master controller and called by `foo`, i.e.:

```
// In your master controller:
$scope.dialogOpen = function(i,j)
{
    $scope.num= i;
    $scope.count = j;
};

// In the controller that contains your $http.Post():
function foo(i,j)
{
    $rootScope.dialogOpen(i,j);
}
$http.post(url,req, "").then(function (response) {
     for (var r = 0; r < response.data.items.length; r++){
         foo(response.data.items[r], r);
     }
});
```

Comment: @Graham Thats what I was looking for and Thanks a lot for your explanation and solution